# How do I completely remove IIS from Windows 10?

Tags: windows, apache-http-server, iis

I installed IIS services through "Turn Windows Features On and Off"
I removed them the same way, I also uninstalled IIS extpres in Add or Remove programs.
I also manually removed C:/Inetpub

I installed XAMPP, but I get the error that Port 80 is in use, so I cannot start apache

It goes away if I run CMD `net stop http`

It seems like IIS is still using this port somehow, it says it's using PID4

If I check the Services tool, I won't see any WWW or Web Publishing Services at all.

How can I get rid of IIS completely so I can use port 80 on apache?

Comment: in an elevated powershell, run `netstat -abno | findstr LISTEN` and note the PID of the process that has a port on 80. you can then run `tasklist` to find out what process goes with that pid. what process is it?

Comment: `System                           4 Services                   0     11,584 K`  Any idea what this is?

Comment: that is the system service, so that does indicate that it is IIS. hmmm

Comment: do you have the service `IIS Admin service`?